# How to burn a DVD which is playable in an external player?

Tags: video, dvd, burning

I have several `.dvd` files which were created using [OpenShot Video Editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com/). To export the videos from OpenShot, I used the DV-NTSC widescreen and DV-PAL Widescreen property.

Can anyone tell me how I can burn these `*.dvd` files into a DVD that can be played with my external Sony CD/DVD 5.1 Player which is connected to a TV?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you do need to make a DVD work for a DVD Player is a program called **DeVeDe NG**.

**1** - Open up Ubuntu Software Centre and in the search field type devede and it will be shown in the results.

**2** - Install that program.

**3** - Start the program and then you will see a series of options.

[image]

**4** - choose **Video DVD**: *Creates a video DVD suitable for all DVD home players*

**5** - You need to add the file to create an **.ISO** so it will work in a DVD Player.

[image]

**6** - In the **Files** section, click **ADD** and then search for the file you want.

**7** - Once you have added the file, click on it and then click on **Properties**

**8** - If the file exceeds 99%, then click on **Adjust Disc Usage**

**9** - Click on the **Video Options** tab and select Scale Picture so there are no black bars (Letterbox Effect)

[image]

**10** - Click **Forward** (check 2nd picture) and choose where you want to save the finished **.ISO**

**11** - Click **OK**

[image]

The **.ISO** will now start to be processed, once it has finished you will then need to burn the .ISO to a blank DVD.  I advise that you burn the .ISO at the slowest speed possible to ensure the best results.

Comment: ^ This method. I burn movies for my kids all the time and they always work in their dvd players.

Answer (score 5):

Open Shot's .dvd files are basically [the same](http://openshotusers.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=815&p=3892) as .vob files for DVD creation. However Open Shot has no DVD authoring module yet.

In the meantime it is recommended to import the .dvd files to a dvd authoring application such as:

- [dvdstyler](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dvdstyler) [image: Install dvdstyler]
- [devede](http://packages.ubuntu.com/devede) [image: Install devede]

Answer (score 3):

If its a standard format, you should be able to right-click the file and select 'burn to disc'. Although I haven't heard of the .dvd file before.

Answer (score 1):

I've found as a new user of Ubuntu that the brasero disc burner is slightly more difficult to get a hold of.  It's not available on the software centre, like it says on the tutorial on the Ubuntu website.  However I did find it here on web:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/yakkety/universe/base/brasero

You can download 32bit and 64bit packages, personally I selected the option to use APT Install.

Obviously you will still need create the iso image first in DeVeDe...Hopefully this will help at least one person.

Comment: Just so you know, you can get Brasero and other software that's available from the universe (contrib) repositories by adding them in "Software Sources". They're available, but not enabled by default because the software in them is not necessarily free, is protected by different licenses, or isn't approved into the main repositories (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I use DeVeDe for making the dvd image file, and then I burn it with Brasero(comes included). I have been having trouble burning discs with devede but making the image file with that program and burning it with another works fine just make sure you know how to get to the image file!