# What DVD authoring software can I use on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, dvd, video-conversion, burning

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. I'm looking for a DVD maker program for Ubuntu like the DVD maker program for Windows. I need to put some videos on DVD (and in DVD format, not just as files) so I can clean up some space on my PC. What can I use to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Brasero to burn a movie in DVD format?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9575/how-do-i-use-brasero-to-burn-a-movie-in-dvd-format) and [How do I create a movie DVD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3617/how-do-i-create-a-movie-dvd) and [How do I burn a DVD which is...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48183/how-to-burn-a-dvd-which-is-playable-in-an-external-player)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Bombono DVD.  It works OK [click Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200202093405/http://www.bombono.org/Home)

Here are the [installation instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120605130541/http://www.bombono.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Install_In_Ubuntu):

> #### Installation In Ubuntu
>
> Bombono DVD is available in Ubuntu 10.04 «Lucid Lynx» and up. Install
> it via Ubuntu Software Center. If you need latest version, see below.
>
> To launch Bombono DVD, just open Applications > Sound & Video >
> Bombono DVD.
>
> #### Latest Bombono DVD For Ubuntu
>
> You can install Bombono DVD from the repository.
>
> On your Ubuntu computer, open System > Administration > Synaptic
> Package Manager. Then choose from menu Settings > Repositories and
> click the Third Party Software tab.
>
> Click the Add button. Copy and paste the following line:
>
> ```
> ppa:muravjov-il/ppa
> ```
>
> Click the Add Source button and close the dialog. Now you are noticed
> that repositories changed, so click the Reload button. Don't worry if
> you see a warning about unverified signatures and unauthenticated
> software; we'll fix that later.
>
> Now you can install Bombono DVD as other software in Synaptic. For
> example, click the Origin button and choose `ppa.launchpad.net/main`.
> Choose `bombono-dvd-testing` entry and install it. For more
> information about using Synaptic Package Manager, see SynapticHowto.
>
> This package is being installed into `/opt/bombono-dvd-testing`
> folder; hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and use
> `/opt/bombono-dvd-testing/bin/bombono-dvd` command to run the program.
>
> Telling Ubuntu how to authenticate the repository
>
> Bombono Repository has GPG signing key BBAB22E8. Open your terminal
> and enter:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BBAB22E8
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Now you don't have any warnings about software can't be authenticated.
> That's all!

<sup>Source: [Install In Ubuntu - Bombono DVD](https://web.archive.org/web/20120605130541/http://www.bombono.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Install_In_Ubuntu)</sup>

Comment: Bombono worked! the menu creator wasnt working right though. so i opted out of the menu.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :)